# apt-get update error Failed to fetch

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager

I am trying to update the repository but it's showing this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this:

```
> #############################################################
> ################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
> #############################################################
> 
> ###### Ubuntu Main Repos deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse deb-src
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe
> multiverse
> 
> ###### Ubuntu Update Repos deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse deb
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
> universe multiverse deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
> precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse deb-src
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
> universe multiverse deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
> precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse deb-src
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted
> universe multiverse
> 
> ###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
> # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
> # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
> 
> ###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
> # deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
> # deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
> # deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse
> # deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main universe multiverse restricted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that delete the `sources.list` and regenerate again. But please, backup your file first.

Open the terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Delete the `sources.list` with this code:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After this open `software-properties-gtk`:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

This will open `software-properties-gtk` and a new `sources.list` will be created automatically.

And check another checkbox, it helps for regenerate the sources.list file. And close, it asks you for delete caches. You can check your `sources.list` file now.

**Edit:**
Also, you can use that [website](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) for regenerate a `sources.list` file.

Comment: Why run `software-properties-gtk` with `sudo`? It will ask for permissions when it needs it.